# Проблема при установке JRE

Tags: java

Вот что выдает при установке: JRE Error code:1618

[image: Вот Что выдает при установке]

Comment: я удивлен, но фаервол помог, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка: JRE Error code:1618

Что необходтмо сделать:

1. Перезагрузить компьютер
2. Отключить антивирус, фаервол
3. Проверьте достаточно ли свободного места на диске,
4. Установить снова